# Cucumber tests fails to start with error "Display socket is taken but lock file is missing.."

Tags: ruby, cucumber, xquartz

After running cucumber

> bundle exec cucumber features/emails.feature:20

I am getting error

> Display socket is taken but lock file is missing - check the Headless
>   troubleshooting guide (Headless::Exception)
>   /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/headless-2.2.0/lib/headless.rb:195:in
>   `ensure_xvfb_is_running' 
>   /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/headless-2.2.0/lib/headless.rb:184:in`
>   launch_xvfb'
>   /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/headless-2.2.0/lib/headless.rb:172:in
>   `block in pick_available_display'

I am running MacOS 10.11.5, xquartz installed, test started first time and I cant make it to start again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Full disclosure: I have no idea what is happening here, and would love for someone to explain it to me, but running the following commands gets Xvfb and my test suite working correctly:

```
mkdir /tmp/.X11-unix
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix
sudo chown root /tmp/.X11-unix/
```

I found this answer here:
https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/issues/47 (first comment)